How do I get Tortoise SVN to ask again for the repository credentials username and password?
How can I resolve resolve this problem?
Tortoise svn was installed on my PC on account A.
I created a new admin local account B
When using new local Windows PC account B I cannot connect to the repository.
I deleted the Tortoise SVN authentication data under settings and after this, it will ask to accept a certificate and after that, for the repository url details but it
NEVER asks for the username and password.
And then fails with
"Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxx...'
Error running context: An error occurred during authentication"

Solution: (applicable 04-2024)
To get this working, I added a new credential to the Windows 11 Credential Manager  for the svn repository url:
Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager\Add a Windows Credential
Under "Internet or network address"  enter the repository url
And then the username and password.
After this, it all worked fine
None of the many solutions that recommend deleting the authentication data, folder in AppData etc worked.
Neither did any of the suggestions to modify the config or server.
